# ubuntu 12.10 mp3 mpeg support

Tags: video-player, mp3-player

Why does ubuntu 12.10 not support playing mp3 audio files and mpeg video right out of the ISO?
These formats have been around for decades now and I find it strange that after I installed 12.10 I could not play an mp3 audio file or an mpeg2 video file.
Why should I have to install something else just to get this function, this should be there as a minimum to be considered an OS in 2012?

Just wondering if I am missing something here or not.

Paul

Comment: just because the formats have been for decades, doesn't mean they are not proprietary. During install you get an option to install these proprietary codecs along with option to install updates.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu asks for that, there is an option during the installation process to let you install additional software for this.

The main reason for this is also the major legal issue with codecs from an user prospective: you are supposed to pay for using the codec that are patented and you are supposed to respect all the patents, trademark and intellectual properties associated with them.

In other words if this wouldn't be optional every Ubuntu user will be forced to pay for this by many international laws that protects this kind of patents.

Same thing applies to every player out there and any kind of software that makes use of patented technologies in general.

Answer (score 0):

I had face same issue but still solve this problem after install mplayer software
Follow it through this site
http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/install-mplayer-with-multimedia-codecs.html

Thanks
DeepakSharma
deepak4win@india.com
India